# What is the type of the LCD of Dell latitude D530?

Tags: laptop, lcd, dell-latitude

There are now several types of LCDs: [PIS, VA, TN...](http://asia.cnet.com/lcd-types-tn-vs-va-vs-ips-62213690.htm) But I have trouble to find what [LCD type Dell Latitude D530](http://www.dell.com/downloads/ap/products/latit/LAT_D530_ANZ_0108.pdf) has, as it is not written in the specs. Maybe at the time of its release there was only one LCD type? But actually this LCD is very good with colour consistency from different angles, so it is not as easy to find out..

Comment: I would imagine it's a TN display - most laptop panels of that time period were. That said, can't absolutely say for certain which type it is without opening it up and Googling the panel used.

Comment: Do you have access to the physical laptop? If you don't then you won't be able to determine this.  If you have access to the laptop there will be a part number or some sort of identification number on the display itself.

Comment: Have it right in front of me, @Ramhound. However I don't see anything written on the display. Where should I look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a TN. (I used the el-cheapo D530 at one of my earlier jobs.)

The D series is a value range, and never used any higher end components so IPS and VAs are out of question. Plus we are talking circa 2008 here (That's when I got my unit, in India so it must be older than that).

EDIT: Look at it from top, even from 15 degree angle the screen should start getting darker. Tell tell TN signs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However I find D530 display of much higher quality than many of today's models!

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by quality? Is it color accuracy, viewing angles, black levels, brightness?

Comment: Viewing angles, colors, the matt-ness, brightness, general feeling... just everything. Also, the keyboard is the best I have seen on laptop - very pleasant to write on, the keys go very light and seem to fit naturally under my fingers... The case also seems very good. And yeah it's still good old 4:3. Many regrets it will have to be replaced.

Comment: For what it's worth, some high-end Thinkpad models had very good IPS screens way before 2008, at least since 2003.